AWS SQS DLQ messages encryption
Send and retrieve messages option allows to retrieve messages from sqs dlq. SSE is enabled but message body is displayed in plain text. Is there is a way to prevent user with permissions to redrive messages from being able to see message content (that might contain PII) in plain text?

I don't think so, no. To redrive a message you need to be able to receive (and decrypt) it from the DLQ, and send (and encrypt) on the queue.

The 1st idea to resolve your case is client side encryption

I notice that Encryption at rest in Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service says: "Moving a message to a dead-letter queue doesn't affect its encryption. When Amazon SQS moves a message from an encrypted source queue to an unencrypted dead-letter queue, the message remains encrypted." Not sure if that helps. One option is to configure the queue to encrypt using a KMS key but limit who can use the KMS key.
